# Issue while sending list of apps to a remote server

Tags: android, json, httpurlconnection

I am developing an android app that should send the list of app installed on a device to a remote server.
Here is the code where I get the app list

```
PackageManager pm = mContext.getPackageManager();
List<ApplicationInfo> apps = pm.getInstalledApplications(0);
applicationInfoToList();//convert apps into a List<String>
for(String s : appListString) {
        //fill the List<String> of the POJO
        mPojo.getmInstalledAppList().add(s);
}

return new Gson().toJson(jsonArray);
```

The String which is returned from the previous method is then passed to the method which takes care of sending the list.
I set the following prop to the HttpUrlConnection instance

```
connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "useragent");
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");
```

The problem is that the json is sent and I can see it on the server but this is the output

```
"message" => "{\\\"values\\\":[\\\"ringtonebackup\\\",\\\"Bestretching\\\",\\\"Thenics\\\",\\\"Package Access Helper\\\",\\\"SCloud Quota Appication\\\",\\\"Google Cerca\\\",\\\"Galleria\\\",\\\"Telefono\\\",\\\"Agg software\\\",\\\"Controlli remoti\\\",\\\"Android Assistant\\\",\\\"BluetoothTest\\\",\\\"Business Calendar\\\",\\\"LinkedIn\\\",\\\"Condivisione Bluetooth\\\",\\\"Memorizz in calendario\\\",\\\"S Voice\\\",\\\"Notifiche di comunicazione\\\",\\\"DeviceTest\\\",\\\"SLW Cache Cleaner Widget\\\",\\\"Samsung Syncadapters\\\",\\\"AllShare FileShare Service\\\",\\\"Camera test\\\",\\\"PickupTutorial\\\",\\\"Download\\\",\\\"RootPA\\\",\\\"Documenti\\\",\\\"VpnDialogs\\\",...]}",
      "tags" => [
    [0] "_jsonparsefailure"
]
```

If instead of sending the list of apps I send a List of random strings that I create, everything works properly.
Moreover, if I run this code on an android emulator the json is sent in the proper format.

Does anyone have an explanation for this behaviour?

Thanks in advance